# How to change currency programmatically on creating order action?

Tags: filters, woocommerce-offtopic, actions

A Payment Gateway I am using expects only Croatian currency so I am trying to update cart total and its currency by using a filter on placing order if the currency is Euro. I have successfully change cart total but I can't change currency. How can I do it inside following action?

```
// Set currency
function change_existing_currency() {
    return 'HRK';
}

function change_total_on_checking($order) {

     // Get order total
    $total = $order->get_total();

     // Change cart total on creating order
    if(get_woocommerce_currency() === 'EUR') {

        // Change currency somewhere here - currently this doesn't work
        add_filter('woocommerce_currency', 'change_existing_currency', 999, 2);

        // Set new cart total
        $new_total = $total * get_currency_rate(); 
        $order->set_total($new_total);

    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'change_total_on_checking', 999, 1 );
```

Comment: Not sure it is the only issue, but you should pass an array to `'woocommerce_currency'` instead of a string. `change_existing_currency()` should return: `return array( 'HRK' => __( 'Croatian kuna', 'textdomain' ), );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found a solution https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/WC_Order/set_currency/php-wc_order-set_currency-method-examples.html

```
$order->set_currency('HRK');
```

Comment: Important: if you're building an API, make sure that the currency is supported & enabled, otherwise the totals will be 0, allowing the customer to place an order without paying. `global $woocommerce_wpml; $enabled_currencies = array_keys($woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency->get_currencies('include_default = true')); if(!in_array($_POST['currency'], $enabled_currencies)) { return new WP_REST_Response([ 'status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Invalid currency', 'fields' => ['currency' => $_POST['currency']] ], 422); }`